# Troubleshooting Mapper Parsing Exception while logging to OpenSearch with Fluentd

Tags: logging, fluentd, opensearch

While trying to send logs from Fluentd to OpenSearch, below errors are being observed. I do not have any explicit mapping types defined on OpenSearch, and it also appears that there isn't any mapping type apart from "text" that can be used in case of this log section

`2023-05-30 11:58:14 +0530 [warn]: #0 fluent/log.rb:351:warn: dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::OpenSearchErrorHandler::OpenSearchError error="400 - Rejected by OpenSearch [error type]: mapper_parsing_exception [reason]: 'failed to parse field [log] of type [text] in document with id 'zNlXa4gB7NIMEpBxp4Zy'. Preview of field's value: '''" location=nil tag="Connectship.BEL.PDC00CSBA304W" time=2023-05-30 11:57:41.842039500 +0530 record={"filename"=>"C:\\ConnectShip\\Logs\\BelError.log", "log"=>"03/13/2023 17:14:14 [44] ERROR ERRORLOGGER - Computer : 5CG9398QYP - User : tcdDEV - Carton Id : 983475934875983 - Error Message : 30005, Package #1: Endicia Web Service error: The Certified Intermediary\x92s pass phrase is incorrect. Error encountered (Log ID: 45961) (3001) .", "hostname"=>"PDC00CSBA304W", "Type"=>"BEL", "host"=>"10.202.115.51"}`

`2023-05-30 11:58:14 +0530 [warn]: #0 fluent/log.rb:351:warn: dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::OpenSearchErrorHandler::OpenSearchError error="400 - Rejected by OpenSearch [error type]: mapper_parsing_exception [reason]: 'failed to parse field [log] of type [text] in document with id 'zdlXa4gB7NIMEpBxp4Zy'. Preview of field's value: '''" location=nil tag="Connectship.BEL.PDC00CSBA304W" time=2023-05-30 11:57:41.842039500 +0530 record={"filename"=>"C:\\ConnectShip\\Logs\\BelError.log", "log"=>"03/13/2023 17:14:37 [44] ERROR ERRORLOGGER - Computer : 5CG9398QYP - User : tcdDEV - Carton Id : 983475934875983 - Error Message : 30005, Package #1: Endicia Web Service error: The Certified Intermediary\x92s pass phrase is incorrect. Error encountered (Log ID: 45983) (3001) .", "hostname"=>"PDC00CSBA304W", "Type"=>"BEL", "host"=>"10.202.115.51"}`

How can I parse these logs and get OpenSearch to accept them? Thanks in advance

The flow of data is from fluent-bit -> fluentd -> Opensearch.

I tried using a fluent-bit modifier to change the "\x" character but that didn't seem to work as expected...

```
[FILTER]
    Name modify
    Match *
    Rename *\x* _x
```

Fluentd Configuration

```
<system>
  log_level error
</system>
<source>
  @type forward
  bind 0.0.0.0
  port 24225
  source_hostname_key host
</source>
<match Connectship.**>
  @type opensearch
##host 10.223.16.105
##port 9200
  hosts 10.223.16.103:9200,10.223.16.100:9200,10.223.16.101:9200
  user admin
  password admin
  scheme https
  index_name connectship11
  ssl_verify false
  @log_level debug
  with_transporter_log true
</match>
```

Comment: can you share your fluentd conf?

Comment: @MusabDogan, I have edited the post to include the fluentd config

Comment: This may mean that the OpenSearch mappings assume the key "log" to be a json while in your case value for "log"  key is  "text"